# jQuery pagination plugin work with tables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, html-table, jquery-pagination

I am wondering if [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) works with tables and if I will be able to display a certain amount of rows per page, like 7 rows on each page?

Also, will it work with the latest version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [DataTables plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DataTables). It allows variable length pagination and works with latest version of jQuery.